# How to use variable value as a pattern in awk command in shell in solaris

Tags: shell

I want to use the variable value from the script in the pattern in awk command but not able to do that, can anybody help like how to do that in Solaris using shell script, below is the script part for reference

Script Part:

```
x=`awk '/Ankur/{print NR:exit}' filename`
```

When I hard-code the string "Ankur", the program works as expected and prints the line number.  However, I have a variable called `var` that contains the string "Ankur" and I would like to supply the value of `var` as a pattern instead.

I tried the following but I'm not getting the desired results:

```
x=`awk '/$var/{print NR:exit}' filename`
```

Thanks

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=shell+quotes

Comment: [Double Quotes](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_02_03)

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead:

```
x=$(awk "/$var/{print NR:exit}" filename)
```

single quote prevents variable expansion, so you need to use double quote.

And use `$()` instead of back-ticks